# Getting tags for a vector in the model Doc2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, doc2vec

I'm trying to implement a KNN without using the KNN function. Once I train the Doc2vec model, is there any method that returns a list of tuples each of the form (vector,tag) because I've set the tag during training to be the class? I'm doing this so I can calculate cosine similarity for a test example vector and each vector in the training set andsort based on it, taking the k highest values and also have the tag available to do a majority vote .

From what I've searched, I can get the vector for a word but not the tag for a trained vector.And, I used the most_similar method which returns somewhat the output I need but it does it using the mean of the data whereas I just want the difference between vectors in training set and test data example as sorting criteria while also having labels available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `Doc2Vec` model `d2v_model`, you can get a list of the (string) tags it learned during training in:

```
d2v_model.docvecs.index2entity
```

For any given tag, you can get its exact vector via:

```
vec = d2v_model.docvecs[tag]
```

If you want to find the tags whose vectors are close to a certain target vector, you can use the `most_similar()` method with a list with the single raw `target_vec` as its `positive` parameter:

```
nearest = d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[target_vec])
```

If you need something else, please be more clear about the form of your training data. (For example, do your documents each include just a single identifier ID, or repeated class labels, or both?)

Comment: My document tags are classes. Multiple documents can have the same class but one document has one class alone. And the positive attribute fed, does that also use the centered mean metric to calculate cosine similarity? I'm basically asking whether there's a mapping given a vector, output its tag.

Comment: In a `Doc2Vec` model, arbitrary vectors don't have tags. Instead, some limited number of tags – those you provided during training – have vectors. So if you have another new arbitrary vector, you can use `most_similar()` to find the nearest tags. So, do that. It's not clear in your questions what, beyond that, you need. (When you try that, what's unacceptable about the ranked-list-of-tags-and-similarity you get back?)

Comment: Note that if you supply only 10 unique class tags, the model will only learn 10 doc-vectors. (You should instead give every text a unique tag if you want to learn doc-vectors for every text, and then learn which existing-texts some new text is nearest-to. Otherwise you've essentially coalesced all examples with the same class into a single combined text.) Showing more about the size & format of your data, and your chosen `Doc2Vec` parameters, might also help. And why you want to do this sorta-KNN, but not use any usual KNN code.